# Python: Generic getters and setters

Tags: python

**TL;DR:  Having to define a unique set of getters and setters for each property()'d variable sucks.  Can I define generic getters and setters and use them with whatever variable I want?**

Let's say I make a class with some nice getters and setters:

```
class Foo
    def getter(self):
        return _bar+' sasquatch'

    def setter(self, value):
        _bar = value+' unicorns'

    bar = property(getter, setter)
```

Pretty great, right?

Now let's say I put in another variable called "baz" and I don't want it to be left out from this sasquatch/unicorn fun.  Well, I guess I could make another set of getters and setters:

```
class Foo
    def bar_getter(self):
        return _bar+' sasquatch'

    def bar_setter(self, value):
        _bar = value+' unicorns'

    bar = property(bar_getter, bar_setter)

    def baz_getter(self):
        return _baz+' sasquatch'

    def baz_setter(self, value):
        _baz = value+' unicorns'

    baz = property(baz_getter, baz_setter)
```

But that's not very DRY and needlessly clutters my code.  I guess I could make it a bit DRYer:

```
class Foo
    def unicornify(self, value):
        return value+' unicorns'

    def sasquatchify(self, value):
        return value+' sasquatch'

    def bar_getter(self):
        return self.sasquatchify(_bar)

    def bar_setter(self, value):
        _bar = self.unicornify(_bar)

    bar = property(bar_getter, bar_setter)

    def baz_getter(self):
        return self.sasquatchify(_baz)

    def baz_setter(self, value):
        _baz = self.unicornify(_baz)

    baz = property(baz_getter, baz_setter)
```

Although that might make my code DRYer, it's not ideal.  If I wanted to unicornify and sasquatchify two more variables, I would have to add four more functions!

There must be a better way to do this.  Can I use a single generic getter and/or setter across multiple variables?

**Unicorn-less and sasquatch-less real-world implementation:**  I'm using SQLAlchemy ORM, and want to transform some of the data when storing and retrieving it from the database.  Some of the transformations are applicable to more than one variable, and I don't want to clutter my classes with getters and setters.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about just:

```
def sasquatchicorn(name):
    return property(lambda self: getattr(self, name) + ' sasquatch',
                    lambda self, val: setattr(self, name, val + ' unicorns'))

class Foo(object):
    bar = sasquatchicorn('_bar')
    baz = sasquatchicorn('_baz')
```

Somewhat more generically:

```
def sasquatchify(val):
    return val + ' sasquatch'

def unicornify(val):
    return val + ' unicorns'

def getset(name, getting, setting):
    return property(lambda self: getting(getattr(self, name)),
                    lambda self, val: setattr(self, name, setting(val)))

class Foo(object):
    bar = getset('_bar', sasquatchify, unicornify)
    baz = getset('_baz', sasquatchify, unicornify)
```

Or, with barely more work, you can use the full descriptor protocol, as described in [agf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10149431/344821).

Comment: But the lambdas limit the setters and getters to a single expressions, which isn't suitable for what I need to do.

Comment: @TheronLuhn So do the same thing but with general functions (either defined as inner functions of `sasquatchicorn` or that take a name as an argument). Or do the full descriptor deal as in [agf](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10149431/344821)'s answer.

Comment: Or do the thing in my edit, which is maybe slightly less work than doing a full descriptor? Maybe? :)

Answer (score 6):

This is what the [descriptor protocol](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html) `property` is based on is for:

```
class Sasicorn(object):                              
    def __init__(self, attr):                        
        self.attr = "_" + attr                       
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):                 
        return getattr(obj, self.attr) + ' sasquatch'
    def __set__(self, obj, value):                   
        setattr(obj, self.attr, value + ' unicorns') 

class Foo(object):                                   
    def __init__(self, value = "bar"):               
        self.bar = value                             
        self.baz = "baz"                             
    bar = Sasicorn('bar')                            
    baz = Sasicorn('baz')                            

foo = Foo()                                          
foo2 = Foo('other')                                  
print foo.bar                                        
# prints bar unicorns sasquatch
print foo.baz                                        
# prints baz unicorns sasquatch
print foo2.bar                                       
# prints other unicorns sasquatch
```

While `property` in a factory function may be fine for your toy example, it sounds like maybe you need more control for your real use case.

Comment: I've been struggling with this for a while, and I might be wrong, but it looks like this will actually define a class-level "property" shared among all instances of the class. This answer is helpful, but that behavior certainly isn't, to me.

Comment: @krs013 You're right, while it showed the descriptor protocol, it wasn't very useful. I've updated it to store the value on the instance rather than the class.

Comment: Thanks, this is the behavior I was looking for. Elsewhere I'd seen it where the descriptor accesses the object's `__dict__` directly, but I think this looks cleaner.

Answer (score 5):

Using [getattribute](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) and [setattr](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) you can define this for all attributes past and future.

```
class Foo(object):                                                                                                                           

  x = 3 

  def __getattribute__(self, attr):
    return str(object.__getattribute__(self, attr)) + ' sasquatch'

  def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
    object.__setattr__(self, attr, str(value) + ' unicorn')

print Foo.x
f = Foo()
print f.x 
f.y = 4 
print f.y
```

This prints:

```
3
3 sasquatch
4 unicorn sasquatch
```

Answer (score 3):

A colleague of mine suggested using closures to return getter and setter functions, which is what I've decided to use.

```
class Foo(object):
    def setter(var):
        def set(self, value):
            setattr(self, var, value+' unicorn')
        return set

    def getter(var):
        def get(self):
            return getattr(self, var)+' sasquatch'
        return get

    bar = property(getter('_bar'), setter('_bar'))

f = Foo()
f.foo = 'hi'
print f.foo
```

But thank you all for your answers :)

Comment: This is essentially the same as Dougal's answer, but uses functions instead of lambdas.

Answer (score -1):

```
# coding=utf-8
__author__ = 'Ahmed Şeref GÜNEYSU'


class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
            self.__setattr__(k, v)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    o = Student(first_name='Ahmed Şeref', last_name='GÜNEYSU')
    print "{0} {1}".format(o.first_name, o.last_name)
    print o.email
```

Gives

```
Ahmed Şeref GÜNEYSU
  File "/Users/ahmed/PycharmProjects/sanbox/abstract_classes/object_initializer/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    print o.email
AttributeError: 'Student' object has no attribute 'email'

Process finished with exit code 137
```