# Create python properties from an array, sharing getters and setters?

Tags: python, properties, python-3.6

I've been working on a python script where every time certain values are changed, a parallel value should be modified as well. For example:

```
self.empire.gold = 345
self.empire.update_times.gold = time.time()
```

Doing this every time was becoming a pain, so I've been researching how to make this happen automatically. This is what I came up with:

```
import time


class boring_object:
    pass


class Object:
    def __init__(self, gold):
        self._gold = gold
        self._updates = boring_object()

    @property
    def gold(self):
        return self._gold

    @gold.setter
    def gold(self, value):
        self._gold = value
        self._updates.gold = time.time()
```

Using this, I can automatically update the time.

However, I want to apply similar setters to a bunch of other resources as well.

I could duplicate this code five times to cover `gold`, `grain`, `potatoes`, etc., but I just want to **pass in an array of the resource names to a constructor and have them share generic getters and setters**. Is that possible?

Before implementing any of this I'm using something closer to the `boring_object()`:

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, array):
        for each in array:
            setattr(self, each, 0)
```

Besides for lacking the property functionality, this doesn't `print()` nicely. Bonus points for a solution that both allows for generic getters and setters and prints nicely without too much extra code.

Once I wrote this up, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10149344/3817111) about getters and setters. One answer suggested [using `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24088820/3817111), which would get me closer to my goal, but I don't want to store update times for and mutate all the attributes which I ultimately set on this object - just the ones named when I initialize it. Other attributes should behave as if there was no custom getter/setter logic.

Comment: Why not put the update time on the descriptor itself?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams sorry, I don't understand?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html

Comment: Just put a guard on your `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` to only accept the values you `__init__` the object with.

Comment: @AChampion and then other attributes will behave as if there was no custom `__getattr__` or `__setattr__`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams from the docs looks like that's along the path I'm looking, but I'm getting outputs like `<__main__.Resource object at 0x7f0e85484278>` when I try to get them and the print lines in the get and set methods aren't being called.

Comment: see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/menasheh/fa610a66b0226ee0bc3ec69e7ecf3a5c) with attempt to use descriptor and output

Comment: The value will always be an object. You need to access it via the attribute if you want what you expect.

Comment: obviously I am missing something

Answer (score 2):

`__getattr__` and the like are nice magical methods that allow you to be clever. However, I advise you not to be. They make your code hard to understand and to follow. Imagine someone else (or you in a year from now) trying to understand [what you did there and why](http://devhumor.com/content/uploads/images/October2014/reading-other-peoples-code.png). If there is an explicit and easy to comprehend approach that gets the job done, I would always prefer this.

A python `@property` is nice if you want to limit access to an attribute or add some small logic to it, like here storing an update time. However, properties don't really fit in your case because you want something that is dynamic and might be configured during runtime. So why not using the obvious? How about some "private" dictionaries (see `_possessions` and `_updates` below) to simply store the empire's resources?

Accordingly, here is my suggestion on how to tackle your problem:

```
import time


class Empire(object):

    def __init__(self, resources):
        self._possessions = {r: 0 for r in resources}
        self._updates = {r: None for r in resources}

    def update(self, resource, value):
        if resource not in self._possessions:
            raise ValueError('Your mighty Empire has no clue what {}'
                             ' really is and how to handle'
                             ' it.'.format(resource))
        self._possessions[resource] = value
        self._updates[resource] = time.time()

    def get(self, resource):
        if resource not in self._possessions:
            raise ValueError('Your poor empire has no {}.'.format(resource))
        return self._possessions[resource]


# Some use cases:
my_little_kingdom = Empire(('gold', 'celebrities', 'vanilla_ice'))

print(my_little_kingdom._updates['gold'])
my_little_kingdom.update('gold', 10)

print(my_little_kingdom.get('gold'))
print(my_little_kingdom._updates['gold'])

try:
    my_little_kingdom.update('bitcoin', 42)
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

### If you insist on attribute access (1st edit)

By the way, if you really, really want to use the fancy `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` methods, you can easily extend the class via

```
def __getattr__(self, item):
    try:
        return self.get(item)
    except ValueError as e:
        # We are trying to get an attribute, so better
        # raise the corresponding error here.
        raise AttributeError(str(e))

def __setattr__(self, key, value):
    if key in ('_possessions', '_updates'):
        # We need to do this to avoid infinite loops.
        # You do see how quickly this gets really complicated!?
        return super().__setattr__(key, value)
    try:
        self.update(key, value)
    except ValueError as e:
        raise AttributeError(str(e))
```

The problem with `__setattr__` becomes quite obvious here. We need to check for *real* attributes to avoid infinite loops. Stuff like this makes your code pretty convoluted. Anyhow, if you added these two magic methods to your `Empire`, you can do this now:

```
my_little_kingdom.gold = 123

print(my_little_kingdom.gold)
print(my_little_kingdom._updates['gold'])

try:
    my_little_kingdom.balloons = 99
except AttributeError as e:
    print(e)
```

### Bonus points: The printable empire (2nd edit)

Of course, to make a pretty printable empire just add this method:

```
def __str__(self):
    possessions = ', '.join('{value} {key}'.format(value=p[1],
                                                   key=p[0])
                            for p in self._possessions.items())
    return ('A glorious and filthy rich empire ' 
            'owning {}.'.format(possessions))
```

Now you can print your kingdom via

```
print(my_little_kingdom)
```

to see this:

`A glorious and filthy rich empire owning 123 gold, 0 celebrities, 0 vanilla_ice.`

Comment: Yes, it's really complicated, that's why I asked here.

Comment: I don't understand how your code deals with real attributes.

Comment: The difference between `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` is that `__getattr__` is only called if the attribute you want is NOT *real*. Yet, `__setattr__` is always called in case you do something like `foo.bar = 42`. So we need to do this check `if key in ('_possessions', '_updates')`, otherwise even calling the constructor of `Empire` would lead to an infinite loop. Why? Because the first statement `self._possessions = {...}` would call `__setattr__` which would subsequently call `update`. `update` in turn uses `self._possessions[...] = ...` which would get you back to `__setattr__` and so on.

Comment: I want to use attributes because I want to loop through a list of attribute names and use setattr

Comment: Why would you want to loop through the attributes? This will involve using and probably implementing `__dir__`. Your project will become really hard to comprehend. Why not directly use a dictionary to store your resources as my answer suggests? Why do you need a complicated solution for a simple problem?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with SmCaterpillar as long as you don't need add new resources (e.g. gold, silver, etc.) at run time, I'd avoid the `__(g|s)etattr__` magic here and use something like the proposed `update` method.